# axis2 vs spring-ws vs jersey

Tags: apache-axis, jersey, spring-ws

My friend asked to explain me what's the difference between Spring, axis2 and Jersey. Here I listed down a few differences that I'm aware of. Please comment/respond if you know more differences

> Spring webservices:
>
> 1. A java web application with a servlet configured in
>      web.xml(org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet).
> 2. You can use spring annotated POJOs for creating web services
> 3. Supports both RESTful and SOAP based web services.
> 4. Since it’s a web application you can use http authentication mechanisms
>      for enabling security
>
> > Axis2:
> >
> > 1. The webservice application is a .aar file that will be deployed in
> >        axis2.war
> > 2. Use AXIOM for using non-primitive type arguments to web service calls
> > 3. You can use JSR181 annotations to create webservices
> > 4. You can use spring-dependency injection using axis2 extensions.
> > 5. Supports both RESTful and SOAP based web services.
> > 6. I guess you have to use ws-security implementation for
> >        providing security
> >        to your web services>
> > 7. They claim hot deployment of webservices works but I haven’t seen
> >        it working.
>
> Jersey:
>
> 1. A regular web application with a servlet configured in web.xml.
> 2. Write custom message readers/writers for using
>      non-primitive type arguments to web
>      service calls
> 3. Since it’s a web application you can use http authentication mechanisms
>      for enabling security
> 4. Supports only RESTful implementation of web services
> 5. I have seen hot deployment working may be because it’s a web application
>      and the container can do hot
>      deployment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jersey and Axis, but I can tell you something about Spring-WS.

You cannot use Spring-WS for restful webservices. Spring-WS is intended to be used for contract first webservices. You can however use the features of Spring 3.x and Spring-MVC for REST services.
As for authorization, you can easily wire in any sort of security (with Spring-Security for instance).

I'm a big fan of the 'automatic' (de) marshalling features of Spring-WS. Just annotate your methods with the correct types and it'll know what to do.